# Custom UITable View Headers disappear after reloading a specific table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with custom headers. and the uitableview row cells have refresh button that will call an API and reload the sender cell. However, whenever a refresh is done, the section headers disappear.

```
extension AccountViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return platforms.count - 1
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BalanceHeaderCell") as? BalanceHeaderCell
        if self.currentUser != nil {
            self.saveUserDefault(item: currentUser?.balance ?? "", key: Account.accountBalanceRecord)
            cell?.headerRefreshButton.tag = section
            cell?.headerRefreshButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshAccountBalanceInfo), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            cell?.set(user: self.currentUser!)
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlatformHeaderCell") as? PlatformHeaderCell
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BankCardsCell", for: indexPath) as? BankCardsCell
        cell?.setCell(bankCount: self.bankCount)
        return cell!
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlatformListCell", for: indexPath) as? PlatformListCell
        cell?.set(platforms: platforms[indexPath.row])
        cell?.platformRefreshButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell?.platformRefreshButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshPlatformBalanceInfo), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        return cell!
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
        return 73
    } else {
        return 40
    }
}
```

What are your suggestions?

Comment: add snippet of your reload part

Comment: At least from the code snippet, it seems you're using the single row in section 0 as a header and I'm assuming that's what's disappearing. Is it possible that when you refresh, self.currentuser is nil and therefore no cell is returned?